# Test project wint stop at breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I created a Visual C++ Native Unit Test Project which I'm trying to debug, but the debugger wont stop at the breakpoint. I'm just clicking "Run All" for the tests to run.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

If i run debug -> start debugging I get this error:

[image]

Comment: "Run All" doesn't (or shouldn't - I am not familiar with visual studio unit test suite) attach the debugger. There should be an option to debug the unit tests (such as "Debug All").

Comment: The compiler could have optimized it away. Try to actually *do* something, like printing or asserting, do something with a side-effect.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have tried with calling code that does something and using asserts. This was just an example.

Comment: Well you'll want to be running a debug config, if the issue is still present then put a break point further back and step over until you get to where you wanted it. If it still skips over, whatever you're trying to debug isn't worth debugging as it probably doesn't do anything anyway.

Comment: @George I'm not able to set a breakpoint anywhere, no matter what I do.

Comment: @Q-bertsuit I wasn't suggesting you to run your test project as if it was a regular application. Did you try Test -> Debug -> All Tests?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It worked! Thanks alot :-D